# login с помощью API. yii2

Tags: php, yii2, api

Мне надо с помощью API авторизоваться в сайте.
с API отправляю $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] на actionLogin().

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        $this->redirect($this->createUrl('site/_allorders'));
    $model = new LoginForm;
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
    }
    $this->layout = 'mini';
    $this->render('_loginForm', array('model' => $model));
}
```

метод $model->validate() нормально проходит, но авторизоваться не получается.
В чем моя ошибка или чего не хватает?

Comment: Так а в каком месте кода вы его, собственно, логините? o_O

Comment: по этому URL: http://...........ru/client.php/site/login находится форма, туда и отправляю пост

Comment: Я имею в виду где вы вызываете метод [`login()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/security-authentication.md#Использование-yiiwebuser-)?

Comment: Изначально не я писал код, но когда проходит валидацыю ($model->validate()), то сразу же авторизуется, может мне гдето ещё нужно писать?

Comment: если так сказать захажу с API, то Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity);  не работает, а если с сайта, то работает. Проблемма в сессии лил где небудь ещё?

Comment: @Taron если API не шарит сессию с приложением, то работать не будет, т.к. `Yii::app()->user->login` (если вы используете стандартный `yii\web\User`) по-сути просто записывает ID пользователя в сессию